# Why is "bereuen" correct in this sentence when it is a transitive verb?

Tags: sentence-structure, prefix

Suddenly the whole concept of "be-" prefix words made sense to me. However, I have an example of something that now conflicts with what I've just learned:

> Ich bereue, dass ich nach dem Abitur nicht länger reisen war.

Why is "Ich bereue" acceptable here? Doesn't a transitive verb require an object? Or is the subordinate clause considered the object of the main clause?

Comment: The same thing happens in English: "I regret my mistake." (transitive). "I regret that I did it." (intransitive with "that" clause). Verbs, especially German verbs, don't always conform to the simple categories people try to put them in.

Comment: @rdbury German grammar considers the "Objektsatz" as an object replacement and thus considers the usage of this verb still as transitive.

Answer (score 6):

Clauses introduced by *dass* are object clauses usually, and they stand in for the accusative object then.

> Er bereut die entgangene Reise nach dem Abitur.
>
> Er bereut, dass ihm die Reise nach dem Abitur entgangen ist.

Only sometimes they are subject clauses:

> Ihn ärgert, dass ihm die Reise nach dem Abitur entgangen ist.
>
> Ihn wurmt, dass ihm die Reise nach dem Abitur entgangen ist.
>
> Ihm gefällt nicht, dass ihm die Reise nach dem Abitur entgangen ist.

Comment: Does this also apply to "ob" clauses?

Comment: No. Those aren't object clauses but indirect questions.